# Change the "COUNT" Text

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

I want to change the word "COUNT" to "No of Reports". Is there any way I can do it. Thanks in advance for helping! Please see the screenshot. I need to change the word in that in circle:

[image: screenshot of "Count"]

Answer (score 0):

Count is displayed using "Modify View" option and COUNT text cannot be changed through sharepoint configuration.

If you must, then you can take help of below optins. However, you will need some advanced skill set for this

1. Sharepoint designer / Add new dataview webpart and change text.
2. Add CEWP above library and change COUNT text at the runtime.

Comment: yes i have the sharepoint designer

Comment: how to change COUNT text at runtime? Can you please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: You will need javascript/jquery knowledge.At the runtime, we can manipulate DOM using Javascript and change any text, color etc. Here is the good example - http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/05/09/adding-script-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp-in-sharepoint-2010-aspx/